# ASP.NET Membership Search

Tags: asp.net, search, asp.net-membership

I did not find any Complete Search for ASP.NET Membership.
for example i want to search a user with this detail :
Username , Creation Date, last Activity Date , Last Login Date , Email , IsUserOnline,IsApproved , IsLockedOut , Has this Roles , Has Not This Roles .
have i load all users in RAM and filter them Server Side ?
this way has bad performance .
is there any better exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Membership` did not provide search functions for the one you ask.

You can use the `Membership.FindUsersByName`, `Membership.GetUserNameByEmail` and some more that you can find on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx), but not the other.

If you have few users that are stored on your web.config file, then just load them all and make your search as you say.

If from the other hand you use a database, then you can connect to the database and get your informations you ask by simple sql query.

Comment: So I will write Stored Procedure for my custom search but is there any written exist ?

Comment: @shaahin, maybe if you google it you can find, but its really so simple, eg: SELECT * FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE ApplicationId='YourAppIdForThis' AND IsLockedOut=1

Comment: @shaahin When you create the database you see the tables, there are really simple.

Answer (score 2):

If the Membership framework doesn't provide the full search functionality you need you could implement a custom membership provider which delivers the specific functionality you need.

If that's too much work, then just roll some stored procedures to query the database yourself and call them when needed. It's not as tidy as keeping everything in the one place, but the schema is pretty simple.

[Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)